# Symfony 2.7 and rendering of choices in Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Trying to render a dropdown in Symfony 2.7.0 but I am having some issues when rendering the choices the view.

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder(null)
->add('timespan', 'choice', array(
     'choices' => array(90 => "3 months", 30 => "1 month")
 ))
 ->getForm();

 ...

 return array(
    'form' => $form->createView(),      
 );

...
```

Doing var_dump after this will display the values:

```
var_dump($form->get('timespan')->getConfig()->getOption('choices'));
```

But when rendering it in the view like this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.timespan, {'class': 'span2'}) }}
```

The select box becomes empty.

```
<select id="form_timespan" name="form[timespan]" required="required" class="span2"></select>
```

Any ideas why this might occur? Am I missing something?

Comment: I think your rendering should look like this: {{ form_widget(form.timespan, {'attr':{'class': 'span2'}} ) }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is obviously in Twig. You can debug this by editing the form theme, to see what values comes in and what is expected. The theme can be found at:

*vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig*

(Or you [can configure Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#twig) to use your own.)

You're looking for `{% block choice_widget %}` specifically to render this.

In this case it looks like you've forgotten to use the `attr` key for your HTML class:

```
{{ form_widget(form.timespan, {'attr': {'class': 'span2'}}) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `attr` key in your call :

```
{{ form_widget(form.timespan, {'attr': {'class': 'span2'}}) }}
```